# Can I use public domain MIDI files commercially?

Tags: copyright, licensing, music, public-domain

Lets say I made professional music with the hope of selling them from public domain MIDI files. The files would have been modified slightly with the notes arranged slightly differently. Would that be legal?

Are the files from [this site](http://midi.music.arizona.edu/) legal?

To clarify, I took the files off of this site, put then into GarageBand, changed the instrument the files were playing, and then looped a ten second clip of it adding drums, bass, etc. I moved the clips around to create my own spin on the files.

Please note: I am aware of the definition of “public domain” and what it means if something is in it.

I live in the US

Comment: Works in the public domain aren't protected by Copyright (by definition). None of the protections of Copyright apply, including the monopoly on making derivative works.

Comment: Therefore what I did is legal? (And ethical)?

Comment: @MusicMan This site has nothing to do with ethics

Comment: No, but silence at that time I was under the impression that my question had been answered I felt that it was an opportune place to ask that question.

Answer (score 3):

### These files are not public domain

Read it carefully, it only says “public domain musical compositions in a MIDI (Musical Instrument Digital Interface) file format.”

The *compositions* are public domain, the MIDI files aren’t - they are a derivative work (a translation) covered by their own copyright. Specifically, “© Copyright 2001 University of Arizona. All rights reserved” right next to a big “Contact us” link. Literary and artistic works that are derived (legally) from existing works have independent copyright even if the original no longer does. Mozart, for example, did not write his compositions in MIDI format.

Now, it may be the intention of the University of Arizona that you can use it but, if so, they have not made this clear. It’s possible that the authors (mistakenly) thought that because the originals were public domain, their derivatives would be too. The music school should have talked to  someone from the law school.

All of the purposes that they talk about on the “Purpose” page are equally applicable to widely licensed (e.g. everyone) or narrowly controlled (e.g. staff of the University).

Overall, a prudent person would assume that these works are copyright of the University of Arizona and can’t be used without permission or a fair use exemption. Your proposed usage is not fair use.

However, there is a big “Contact us” link on every page so you can always ask for permission.

Comment: I understand U of A thinks the MIDI files are copyright and I agree about prudence but is a MIDI file a translation or a transliteration? A non-creative, mechanical transliteration would arguably not result in a new copyrightable expression

Comment: Shoot, I had assumed it was copyright for the webpage design.

Comment: Although would the files technically be public domain sience midi are “not considered, so far, to be a "fixed and tangible medium" for purposes of copyright law.” According to a quora entry I read. In fact, apparently you can't even register a MIDI file with the U.S. Copyright office, but rather you must submit it as either printed sheet music, CD Audio, Tape Audio, etc. So would the files be public domain with that in mind?

Comment: You answered a similar  question here https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/40985/how-are-midi-files-of-copyrighted-music-licensed?rq=1

Comment: @MusicMan bits on a hard drive are a “tangible form”

Comment: Do you think I would be likely to be sued if I used them?

Comment: I do plan to contact then and ask, I am just wondering.

Comment: However, I am transforming the files quite a bit, would this classify it as fair use?

Comment: @MusicMan a derivative work is a derivative work no matter how much transformation happens. If you transformed them into, say visual art, then that might be sufficiently transformative to make the work non-derivative.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much for your help. (Although I do wonder how you would turn music into visual art)

Comment: @music it is possible to have a computer program where each note specifies the color and position of a dot or blob. Music or sound is input, and an image is output. On the other hand, some painters create abstract works "inspired" by musical works.

Comment: Huh. Cool......

Comment: Re "*However, I am transforming the files quite a bit, would this classify it as fair use?*", Quite the opposite. Transforming a Copyright work points to infringement. The right to limit derivative works is one of the rights granted by Copyright. One of the four factors to evaluate if something is fair use is called the transformative use factor, but it doesn't refer to this. It refers to changes in how the work is used (entertainment vs news reporting, art installation vs commentary, etc)

Comment: @MusicMan the university calls these "useable" music files and says that the files are designed "to be manipulated to suit individual needs." The assessment in this answer that the university has not made their intention clear that you can use the files is not well founded. Furthermore, as George White has noted, mechanical transcription is not covered, so it's very likely that these files are not protected in the US. And I think you were right that the copyright notice is intended to refer to the webpage design and the text, so even if they're protected, U of A probably won't claim anything.

Comment: @phoog from the description it appears that there has been considerably more effort in these files than simple transcription. It’s also not clear if any implicit permission that may be there is just for staff/students or the general public.

Comment: The site was also that the site references does not exist. So I believe that they have likely forgotten about the site. Therefore most likely it is ok to use the files as a not student.